# What is the difference between a view and a layout in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference? I ask because I'm just starting RoR dev, and I need to modify an application to add a new div to a page.  I want to be able to render this div independently, and currently the rhtml code is part of the view of the page that will be rendered.  I assume I would need to move this into a partial layout from what I have gathered so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view is context based, i.e. related to the particular controller#action you are hitting based on the RESTful URL being requested.  The controller#action serves your request and delegates the appropriate view to be yielded back to your base-application template.

You will find `<%= yield %>` in your `application.html.erb` for this very reason.

As for your first question, Bessam is correct and you need to look at partials.

Answer (score 8):

What you need is a partial view not a partial layout.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

The layout is a template that contains shared DOM components, the View is what fills this template.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html